# pattern matching in DB2 SQl

Tags: sql, db2, pattern-matching

I have a table

```
Marks_Table (
MARKS_ID         NUMBER,
ST_ID            NUMBER,
MARK_DESC        VARCHAR(20),
MARKS            NUMBER
)
```

Now, MARK_DESC, contains the desciption of the Marks. Now i want to have the rows in the table which contains `test` in the description.

Now the problem is, that the description may contains `test` in any pattern, it may be `Test`, `test`, `TeSt`, `tEST` and so on..

How to fetch the rows with the above conditions.?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about the "UPPER" function?

```
select * from marks_table where upper(mark_desc) like '%TEST%'
```

Comment: Actually, i thought of this, but i don't want to add any operation on the column, instead If I can add some sort of pattern matching on the right side of the equaltion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Marks_Table (
MARKS_ID         NUMBER,
ST_ID            NUMBER,
MARK_DESC        VARCHAR(20),
MARKS            NUMBER,
MARK_search      VARCHAR(20),
)
```

and insert MARK_search as something like normate(MARK_DESC) with removing spaces and uppercase with a (insert/update) trigger and a stored procedure